# Find the value $\int_{-\frac\pi8}^{\frac\pi8}[|x|+\tan(2x)]^2{\rm d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, absolute-value

> $$\int_{-\frac\pi8}^{\frac\pi8}[|x|+\tan(2x)]^2{\rm d}x$$

I am a newbie to calculus and I have no idea on how to do this question. Please help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried the usual thing for absolute values in integrands: split the interval of integration into pieces where the sign of the thing in absolute values is constant on each piece, then integrate the pieces separately and add them up?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions, rather than posting images.  Images can't be searched, and aren't accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: oic..thanks Eric, saulspatz and mrtaurho!

Comment: @EricTowers I have been taught of this method years ago..but just have no idea on how to apply to this question

Comment: Does anyone have any idea on this TT